# Android change value of Spinner

Tags: android, spinner

I created 2 `Spinner`s and I to fill them with an array of numbers. What I want is that the  user chooses the number they want on the first one, and then I save it to a variable that I use to populate the dropdown list of the second one with values that start with that number. How can I do this?
How can I change the text in the second spinner to start with the number chosen.

I have this, I store the item of the `Spinner` on the variable `x`, and I want a second `Spinner` to start with that variable.

```
mySpinner
                .setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(NewGuiaActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        establist));

        // Spinner on item click listener
        mySpinner
                .setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                            View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        // Locate the textviews in activity_main.xml


                        x = estab.get(position).getID();

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), x,
                                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you want to do correctly, for example if you select the number 4 from the drop down of spinner1, you want spinner2 to be set to the 4th position in it's list:

Try something like this, say you have `mySpinner1` and `mySpinner2`, let your class `implement OnItemSelectedListener` and give it a class variable `private int spinner2Pos = 0;`

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) parent;
    if(spinner.getId() == case R.id.spinner_1_id){
        spinner2Pos = 
                (spinner.getItemAtPosition(position) < mySpinner2.getAdapter().getCount())?
                spinner.getItemAtPosition(position): 0;
        mySpinner2.setSelection(spinner2Pos);
    }
}
```

This should set mySpinner2 to the item you select with mySpinner1, which is stored as a class variable spinner2Pos. I haven't had time to check it so let me know if there are errors.

Comment: only needed this  mySpinner2.setSelection(spinner2Pos); thanks men

Comment: @user3704985 You may want to include the entire if statement, it is to make sure that you don't try to set it to a non-existent value. Glad it helped.